# Add private sub class to Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

How to add MySubClass to Q_DECLARE_METATYPE.

This is sample code and please ignoring business of code.

```
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

namespace MyNS {
    class MyClass : public QObject {
    public:
        MyClass() : value(0) { }
        MyClass(int value) : value(value) { }
        MyClass(const MyClass &other) { value = other.value; }
        ~MyClass() { }
        int getValue() const {
            MySubClass msc(value);
            QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(msc);
            int tempV = v.value<MySubClass>().getSubValue();
            return tempV;
        }
    private:
        class MySubClass
        {
        public:
            MySubClass() : subValue(0) {}
            MySubClass(int v) : subValue(v)
            {

            }
            int getSubValue()
            {
                return subValue;
            }
        private:
            int subValue;
        };
//        Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MySubClass);  error : 'QMetaTypeId<MyNS::MyClass::MySubClass>': cannot specialize template in current scope
        int value;
    };

//    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MySubClass);  error : 'MySubClass': undeclared identifier
}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyNS::MyClass);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyNS::MyClass m(15);
    QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(m);
    qDebug() << v.canConvert<MyNS::MyClass>();
    qDebug() << v.value<MyNS::MyClass>().getValue();
}
```

Consider **MyClass** works well without subcalss, but my problem with subclass. I want to use **MySubClass** with QVariant in my code, but MySubClass is private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the use of `QMetaType` for your `MySubClass`, it needs to be publically accessible.

Think about why you want to insert `MySubClass` into Qt's meta type system?

**If** you want to be able to send `MySubClass` via signal/slot, or (de)serialize / stream it, that would make `MySubClass` be of **public** interest. [The docs tell you so](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/custom-types.html):

> Before we begin, we need to ensure that the custom type we are creating meets all the requirements imposed by QMetaType. In other words, it must provide:
>
> ```
> a public default constructor,
> a public copy constructor, and
> a public destructor.
> ```

**If** you just want to store `MySubClass` instances in `QVariant`, you can write your own conversion methods

```
QVariant toVariant() const
```

and

```
(static) MySubClass fromVariant(QVariant const &v)
```

To be type-safe you could create some public dummy type and register it with `QMetaType` so you'd get a unique ID, but basically you'd convert your `MySubClass` to a `QVariantMap` and back, provided that all contained data is storable in a `QVariant`.